# How to download file from Sftp server to local machine

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I have to download file from Sftp server to local machine. I am creating a connection by using the phpseclib. It is connected with Sftp server. But I have to download a file from server to local machine. How can i do that. I am using this code to download dummy.txt from remote server to local machine. Please help

```
public function startProcess() {

    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.com');

    if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
    else {
        echo "connected";
    }

    echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
    downloadfiles('/path to server/dummy.txt');      
}

public function downloadfiles($filename)
{
    if($filename)
    {
        $remote=file_get_contents($filename);
        $local_file_path='localpath/adobe.txt';
        file_put_contents($local_file_path,$remote);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error download files";
    }

}
```

Please help me to sought it out.

Comment: Oh no! Your `Enter` key appears to be stuck!

Comment: Is the local machine running the php script or is that on a separate server?

Comment: It is local machine.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? You should add some error handling to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a file from an SFTP server using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145779/how-to-download-a-file-from-an-sftp-server-using-php)

Comment: It is not downloaded any file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're not doing `$sftp->get()` anywhere, for one.

Below is a re-worked version of your code to enable downloads:

```
global $sftp;

public function startProcess() {

    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.com');

    if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
    else {
        echo "connected";
    }

    echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
    downloadfiles('/path to server/dummy.txt');      
}

public function downloadfiles($filename)
{
    if($filename)
    {
        $local_file_path='localpath/adobe.txt';
        $sftp->get($filename, $local_file_path);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error download files";
    }

}
```

Comment: $local_file_path='localpath/adobe.txt'; line in your code, should not it be a folder ? instead of a path with file name ?