# Sftp file download from web

Tags: php, ftp, sftp

I have file in ftp (sftp) server. And once a user clicks on a button in the webpage user must be able to download that file. Backend server is php. What I'm planning to do is first download that file to the backend server from ftp server and store it localy and then let the user to download it from there by  a url. Is there any other way to bypass this and enable user to directly download the file from the ftp server by just clicking the button?

ps: I'm using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) to create the sftp communication.

Comment: You just do not need to store the file on the server, you can download it in-memory and just dump it to the HTTP response.

Comment: Found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145779/how-to-download-a-file-from-an-sftp-server-using-php